# Disadvantages If use morethan one controllers in Sencha-Touch MVC?

Tags: sencha-touch

I am developing Sencha-Touch 1.1.0 MVC based mobile web-app. Before that I had checked, all application based on Sencha-Touch MVC having one controller. can you please tell me is there any memory issue or performance issue there if used more than one controller Secnha-Touch MVC and let me know what are the disadvantages of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you had checked but most application in fact have more than one controller. There is absolutely no reason why to use only one controller and there are certainly no disadvantages if you use more than one controller.

It all depends on your app's business logic. In each MVC application you can use as many as you need models, views and controllers.